# Store view for CMS->Pages grid preview link

Tags: admin, multistore, store-view, grid

Is there any way to change store view for CMS->Pages without code modification?

I am asking this because I built a custom modul CMS->My module which has similar grid as Pages (this is why I gave Pages as example). My module grid has preview link inside. For preview link I took default store view. By my customer says that he wants to be link for selected store view. I am confused because for CMS->Pages there is no select store view selection. It is only for System->Configuration. How he can change store view for CMS->Pages grid. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

If you were to setup multiple store views then there does become an option for this on each page as per the images below. However if you only have one store views these are not shown for obvious reasons, which I suspect is why you don't see them?

[image]